# Java How to display string like this

Tags: java, netbeans

My program will take a string from user via a text field 
when he presses the button the string should be formatted as shown in the example

An Example will help you understand better

> If String Entered is "hello"

Output should be

hello

elloh

llohe

lohel

ohell

hello

The first character must shift to last until the initial word is formed again.

> This must work for any length of string
>
> `Displaystr =newStr.charAt(newStr.length() - 1) + newStr.substring(0, newStr.length - 1);`
>
> I tried this code but It didn't help

Edited - Please don't put question on hold now.

Comment: I smell homework. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: An introductory tutorial on Java would be a good place to start.

Comment: thats easy!
if(input.equals("hello"))
{
system.out.println("hello");
system.out.println("elloh");
system.out.println("llohe");
system.out.println("lohel");
system.out.println("ohell");
system.out.println("hello");
}

Comment: Or better: `if(input.equals("hello")) {Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777924/java-how-to-display-string-like-this"));}`

Comment: My method is more portable! :v

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not conform to the homework guidelines.

Comment: if(input.equals("hello")) System.out.println("hello\nelloh\nllohe\nlohel\nohell\nhello");

Comment: This should work for any string not just hello, don't act like this.I would not have asked this If it was that simple

Comment: Says the lazy person who just dumps his homework here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    public  class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(text);
        for(int j=0;j<text.length();j++) {
            char firstLetter = text.charAt(0); //get the first letter
            text = text.substring(1); //remove the first letter from the input string
            text = text + firstLetter;
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sb` isn't used.  And it doesn't output the first "hello".

Comment: Yes, i forgot about the StringBuilder, wasn't sure whether to use it. And thanks for pointing out that i wasn't printing the word first. I think i fixed it

Comment: It can be modified to display first "hello ".I got the logic.Thanks a lot @AlexanderMladzhov

Comment: No problem Shub, glad I could help